# Rails create a grouped unordered list using table that references itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a category table that looks like:

```
id store_id parent_category_id name
1  1        nil                Footwear
5  1        1                  Men's Shoes
7  2        nil                Accessories
22 2        7                  Watch
```

What I'm trying to do is create a filter on my index page based on association to the category if they match. Where I'm struggling is getting the group/sort to work for the design. What I'm trying to display is something like the following:

```css
p {
display: inline-block;
padding-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a href="#homeSubmenu1" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Footwear</a>
      <p>2,000</p>
      <ul class="collapse list-style-upper" id="homeSubmenu1">
        <li><a href="home-sub-submenu1">Men's Shoes</a>
        <p>1,000</p>
          <ul class="list-style-upper-sub">
            <li>Adidas<p>1,000</p></li>
            <li>Nike<p>500</p></li>
            <li>Convers<p>500</p></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Women's Shoes</a><p>500</p></li>
        <li><a href="#">Children's Shoes</a><p>500</p></li>
        <li><a href="#">Socks<p>100</p></a>
          <ul class="list-style-upper-sub">
            <li>Blue<p>50</p></li>
            <li>Red<p>25</p></li>
            <li>Green<p>25</p></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

So far I've built out the parent method to capture the parents based on being nil:

```
def parent_category
 Connector::Category.where(parent_category_id: [nil, ''])
end
```

This pulls in the correct parents but I can't quite figure out how to group by the parent_category_id and then apply the correct links to apply filtering. I've tried things like:

```
<ul class="nav">
 <% Connector::Category.group(:name).each do |x|%>
   <li><%=x.name.titleize%></li>
 <%end%>
</ul>
```

This results in PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "connector_categories.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.

So then I thought I'll just put this on the index method for the products index page (where this appearing) with the following:

```
def index
 query = query_products
 query = query.search(params[:search]) if params[:search]
 @products = query.order(sortable_query).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
 @category = Connector::Category.select(:id, :name).all.order('number ASC').group(:parent_category_id)
end
<ul class="nav">
  <%@category.all.each do |X|%>
   <li><%=x.name%></li>
  <%end%>
</ul>
```

This results in formal argument cannot be a constant.

So how do I create a grouped unordered list using a table that references itself?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the task is to show a tree of categories? What do numbers next to each category mean?

Comment: That's the count of products that have the categories. So in my example footwear has 2,000 products and each branch has it's separate amount equaling up.

Comment: Just want to confirm -- the task is to show a tree of categories, as in your code snippet, correct?

Comment: Yeah it would be showing the tree of categories that would eventually have drop-downs, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Talking about showing a tree of categories. Instead of constructing complicated queries with grouping to the database I would recommend to fetch all categories with a SINGLE plain `SELECT` query and build nested tree programmatically, such as:

```
@categories = Connector::Category.includes(:products).group_by { |category| category.parent_category_id }
```

Thus root categories (without parent) will be available as `@categories[nil]`. You can start showing the tree of categories with `each`-loop over this list. For each root category `cat` the list of their children will be accessible as `@categories[cat.id]`.

Since nesting of category tree can be quite deep (there can be children, grandchildren, grand-grandchildren, etc) I would recommend create a partial to show children of given category and call it recursively. Example:

```
# _category_item.html.erb

<li>
  <a href="#"><%= category.name =><p><%= category.products.count %></p></a>
  <% if @categories[category.id].present? %>
    <ul class="list-style-upper-sub">
      <% @categories[category.id].each do |child| %>
        <%= render 'category_item', category: child %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

and in the main view:

```
# index.html.erb

<ul class="list-style-upper">
  <% @categories[nil].each do |root| %>
    <%= render 'category_item', category: root %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

> Off-topic: rendering category tree recursively may fail if it has loops: for example, category A is a parent of category B, which is a parent of category A again, or category A is a parent for itself. You need to make sure the tree does not have such loops.

Comment: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass on the @categories[nil]. I probably also should have mentioned that Products and Categories are connected through a join table so the query isn't working at the moment

Comment: @Jake It doesn't matter if products and categories joined through a separate table or directly. If `Category` model has associated with `Product` model (via `has_many` or `has_many through`), the method `includes(:products)` works for it. If your tables have no such relationship, then just remove `includes` from AR call and `category.products.count` from the partial.

Comment: `@categories = ...` should be in the `index` action of the controller. Even if there is no categories, it should return an empty array. Please make sure it works.

Comment: So it's being referenced in the layouts/application.html.erb not the index page. I do have it in the CategoriesController under the index method

Comment: Ah, if you're going to show this category tree not on index page of categories, but on all other pages, you can move that `@categories = ` calculation to `before_filter`, for example, to make sure it is available for every action where it is needed. The other option is to use helper